# how to replace multiple words using javascript replace() function?

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```
        var keys = keyword.split(' ');
        //alert(keys);
        for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
            {
            var re = new RegExp(keys[i], "gi");
            var NewString = oldvar.replace(re, '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">'+keys[i]+'</span>');
            document.getElementById("wordlist").innerHTML=NewString;
            alert(keys[i]);
            }
```

but here if I put a string "a b"; its split into two letters "a" and "b"
and this replace function replace "a" but when it get "b" it overwrite and only replace "b".
but I want to highlight both "a" and "b".
how to solve this?
I got another problem . If I replace/highlight it then it replace all "a" and "b" of HTML tag. so, how to prevent to replace those html tag. but also when I display the whole text I need all html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do a single regex replace like this:

```
var re = new RegExp(keys.join("|"), "gi");
oldvar = oldvar.replace(re, replacer);        
document.getElementById("wordlist").innerHTML = oldvar;

function replacer(str)  
{  
    return '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">' + str + '</span>';
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/1/

What it is doing is merging all keys into a single regex seperated by `|` which will match all the words then running the replacer function on the matches.

Example 2 - http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/2/

Comment: if this keys dynamic then this code is not working. and still it replace HTML tag. I want to prevent to replace html tag. please help to solve this

Comment: @Moumita I don't know what you mean, I've added another example that allows different values to be passed to the function, does this do what you need?

Comment: I didi this: http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/3/   here my string have some html content. and I want to dispaly it with these html content. but also i want to replace only text into those html tag. what i should do?

Comment: i think I need to check all **"<div>
    <ul>
      <li id="txtId"><a onclick="word_desc(27); classChange(1, 1);" id="txtid1" class="sel25" >"** and **"</a></li></ul></div>"** using regex  but how???

Comment: check this is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/7/ I dont want to highlight any html tag,

Comment: @Moumita That makes it a lot harder. If you could use jQuery you could maybe loop through the elements and update their text values rather than HTML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4262/discussion-between-moumita-and-richard-d)

Comment: I'm in chat room . please reply there

Answer (score 2):

```
    var keys = keyword.split(' ');
    //alert(keys);
    for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
        {
        var re = new RegExp(keys[i], "gi");
        oldvar = oldvar.replace(re, '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">'+keys[i]+'</span>');
        document.getElementById("wordlist").innerHTML=oldvar;
        alert(keys[i]);
        }
```

Edit:
It seems obvious that oldvar is not changed durring the loop always only last replace is applyied. You have to change "oldvar" in order to replace all the words

Answer (score 1):

You should do the Operations on the same var. You take oldvar outside of the loop, but never take the changed content into oldvar. So the last iteration (only) is the one which replaces the content.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `replace` on the variable `oldvar` (which is not declared in this snippet) in each iteration and thus starting from  the same point - the non-highlighted string - every time. Without having seen all of the code, I would guess that simply replacing `var NewString =` with `oldvar =` and `.innerHTML=NewString` with `.innerHTML=oldvar` will solve your problem.